# a house Up For Sale

Tags: meaning

A [post](https://www.indiewire.com/2016/09/harry-potter-privet-drive-sale-sorcerers-stone-j-k-rowling-1201728435/) uses this title

> Harry Potter’s On-Screen Home At Privet Drive **Up** For Sale

What does "up" here mean? Does it mean "ready"?

Answer (score 1):

To "put up for sale" means to offer for sale. "Up for sale" is a shortening of that idiom, used as an adjective. So that home has been put up for sale.

[Merriam-Webster "put up"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put-up) 
"to make available, especially : to offer for public sale
 *put their possessions up for auction*